# AnimationDrawable unable to clear frames

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation

I am trying to problematically add frames and duration to an AnimationDrawable but I cannot get the result I want.  I can add the frames but subsequent calls do not clear the old frames.  Is there a way to reset an AnimationDrawable?

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
public void animate() {

    if (a != null && a.isRunning()) {
        a.stop();   
    }

    //iv.setImageDrawable(null);
    //iv.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank_animation);
    a = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();

    a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blank), 1);
    for (int i=0;i<Frames.size();i++) {

        a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(Frames.get(i)), AnimationSpeed);

    }
    a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blank), 1);

    a.setOneShot(true);
    a.start();

}
```

I have tried the following without success to clear either the ImageView and/or the AnimationDrawable.

```
iv.setImageDrawable(null);
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
a = new AnimationDrawable();
iv.clearAnimation();
```

I have also tried to null the ImageView and recreate it and that did not reset the frames.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that

```
a = new AnimationDrawable();
a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blank), 1);
for (int i=0;i<Frames.size();i++) {
    a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(Frames.get(i)), AnimationSpeed);
}
a.addFrame(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blank), 1);
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(a);

a.setOneShot(true);
a.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @jobesu14 that worked! The only problem was     a.setBackgroundDrawable(anim); should be     iv.setBackgroundDrawable(a);.  The ImageView must be set to the AnimationDrawable.